# Bash globs as non-file arguments. Example: apt-get remove pkg-*

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

I know `*` and other glob patterns are transformed into words by pathname expansion, based on the current working directory. Hovever, some commands seem to use them for non file arguments. For example, I use `dpkg -l pkg-*` to list the packages with `pkg-`. I thought programs could not see their arguments before expansion, only after. Is this not the case? How does this work?

I recently read about some bash weirdness the author called [magic aliases](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/aliases.html), which I think could be used to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that if `pkg-*` does not match any file in current directory it's passed to dpkg as it is.  It's actually bad idea.  One should quote it all the time.  For example: `dpkg -l pkg-\*`

Comment: This is absolutely insane.

Answer (score 0):

You're right: programs can only see their arguments after they've been expanded by the shell, they can't see the original wildcards. However, the Bourne shell and its successors (ksh, bash, dash, …) leave wildcards unexpanded if they match 0 files. So as long as there is no file whose name begins with `pkg-` in the current directory, `dpkg -l pkg*` passes the two arguments `-l` and `pkg-*` to `dpkg`.

This is done as a convenience to avoid having to quote wildcard characters in words that weren't intended to be interpreted as file names and don't match any file name. But some shells behave differently and can either abort the command if the wildcards match nothing (default behavior in csh, tcsh, zsh and fish — except that when there are several consecutive patterns, it's OK for some of them to match nothing as long as at least one does match a file) or expand wildcards matching nothing to nothing (`N` glob modifier or `null_glob` shell option in zsh, `N` pattern option in ksh, `nullglob` shell option in bash). This latter behavior has the advantage of regularity (a non-matching pattern expands to the list of matches, same as one that matches one or more files) which makes it preferable in scripts.

To ensure that a pattern won't be accidentally expanded, quote its wildcard characters: `dpkg -l 'pkg-*'` or `dpkg -l pkg-\*`.

None of the usual shells are aware of which arguments of which commands are files (where globbing is desirable) and which ones are other things that should ideally be left alone. Zsh can be made to disable globbing for a specific command by writing `noglob` before it, e.g. `noglob dpkg -l pkg-*`. `noglob` is often used in an alias like `alias lynx='noglob lynx'`. The bash “magic aliases” described by Simon Tatham simulate zsh's `noglob`.